# Puppet gem provider on windows

Tags: rubygems, puppet

I am using Puppet Agent for Windows version 3.0 and i was trying to use the **gem** provider as well with the following resource

```
package { 'nokogiri':
    ensure => '1.5.5',
    provider => 'gem'
}
```

It seems that when i execute the **apply** command the gem is installed on the ruby 1.8.7 directory that gets bundled within the puppet client installer for windows.

I am trying to install Ruby 1.9.3 on windows as a separate package that will be available for other purposes.

```
class ruby{

file {'ruby':
    name => 'C:\Temp\rubyinstaller-1.9.3-p194.exe',
    ensure => present,
    source => 'V:\shardata\Puppet\rubyinstaller-1.9.3-p194.exe'
}


exec { 'ruby':
        command => 'C:\Temp\rubyinstaller-1.9.3-p194.exe /verysilent /dir="C:\ruby" /tasks="assocfiles,modpath"',
        require => File["ruby"]
    }


package { 'nokogiri':
    ensure => 'latest',
    provider => 'gem',
    require => Exec['ruby']
}

}
```

Should I use the Exec resource type on windows instead of the package/gem combination?

Comment: Did you figure out how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

When I have multiple rubies to install, I use rvm (http://rvm.io).  It installs very easily and handles setting up your environment, rubies and gemsets.  I would suggest explicitly setting your ruby (1.9.3 or 1.8.7, etc.) and gemset and sourcing rvm to ensure your environment is set.

Comment: I think rvm is very complex to install on windows. I guess i should around with the **exec** resource type to install specific gems targeting the gem.bat at the ruby bin folder

Comment: What about using Exec like this.

        exec { 'nokogiri':
     path => 'C:\ruby\bin', 
  command => 'gem.bat install nokogiri -v "1.5.5"',
  logoutput => true,
  
        }

Comment: I have no experience with rvm on windows, so it could be a bear.  Good luck.